# SQL multi layer headers

Tags: sql, header

Is there any way I can create multi layer headers in a table? For example. I am planning to create report for last month report but in output header I want "Last month report" header and sub header "server" and "application"

```
______________________________________________
   Last Month Report    |  Last year report   |
________________________|_____________________|
Server   |   Application| Server   | Apps     |
________________________|______________________
xyz      |     tomcat   |....      | .....    |
abc      |     apache   |....      | .....    |
....     |     ......   |....      | .....    |
```

is it possible to create above headers layout ?

Comment: What's your reporting system? This is not something you do with SQL.

Comment: What type of Database is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you would do this is with a plain SQL query like this:

```
 select LastMonthServer, LastMonthApplication, LastYearServer, LastYearApps
 from ....
 where ....
 order by ...
```

And then simply configure your report layout however you want it, in whatever reporting system you're using.

SQL databases do not deal with presentation, just the structure of the data.

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer - No. This is a presentation concern, use an application or reporting framework to format data in this way.

Comment: Thanks for quick and sweet reply :)